# Local rings whose the endomorphism rings of E(R/J) is division ring

Tags: noncommutative-rings, local-rings

Let $R$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $J$. Assume that ${\rm End}_{R}({\rm E}(R/J))$ is a division ring (${\rm E}(R/J)$ means the injective envelope of $R/J$). Does $R/J$ is injective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(R/J)_R$ will be injective only in trivial cases.

For a local ring, the only simple module is $R/J(R)$.  If that is an injective right module, then it is a [right V-ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-ring_(ring_theory)), but V-rings are all semiprimitive, so it would mean $R$ is already a division ring.

So if you have a particular example in hand where $J\neq \{0\}$, you can rest assured $R/J$ is not an injective $R$ module.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. This is right. In fact I am searching for an example.  However in commutative case, I proved that if $R$ is a local ring and ${\rm End}_{R}(E(R/J))$ is division ring then $R$ must be a field. But in general case, I do not know.